# how to add arrow when sub-menus having another Sub-menus in asp

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, menu

How to Add Arrow Symbol While Sub Menu Having Another Sub Menu in Menu ,,
Am Using ASP ,, I want to Display Menu , Menu Contains 4 items, Each items Having Sub menu, again Each Sub Menu having another Sub menu,, In this Concept i Want to use Arrow mark to display the Sub menu Items,which sub menu items having sub menu means it will display the arrow near that Sub menu,, My vb Coding Like

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        Dim data As New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim strcon As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("sample").ConnectionString
        Dim con As New SqlConnection(strcon)
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("Select MenuID, Menus from PagesDetails", con)
        Dim dttc As New DataTable()
        da.Fill(dttc)
        Dim main As HtmlGenericControl = UList("Menuid", "menu")
        Dim dtDist As New DataTable()
        For Each row As DataRow In dttc.Rows
            ' For row As Integer = 0 To dttc.Rows.Count - 1
            'dtDist.Columns.Clear()
            cmd.Parameters.Clear()
            dtDist.Clear()
            cmd.CommandText = "FindMenus"
            cmd.Connection = con
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToString(Session("UserId"))
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@MenuId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = row("MenuID").ToString()
            data.SelectCommand = cmd
            data.Fill(dtDist)
            If dtDist.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                Dim sub_menu As HtmlGenericControl = LIList(row("Menus").ToString(), row("MenuID").ToString())
                Dim ul As New HtmlGenericControl("ul")
                Dim mains As HtmlGenericControl = UList("SubMenuId", "menu")
                For Each r As DataRow In dtDist.Rows
                    ul.Controls.Add(LIList(r("SubMenu").ToString(), r("SubMenuId").ToString()))
                    If r IsNot Nothing Then
                        cmd.Parameters.Clear()
                        Dim dtsub As New DataTable
                        Dim data1 As New SqlDataAdapter
                        cmd.CommandText = "Menusfind"
                        cmd.Connection = con
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToString(Session("UserId"))
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@MenuId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = row("MenuID").ToString()
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@SubMenuId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = r("SubMenuId").ToString()
                        data1.SelectCommand = cmd
                        data1.Fill(dtsub)
                        Dim ul1 As New HtmlGenericControl("ul")
                        Dim sub_menu2 As HtmlGenericControl = LIList(r("SubMenu").ToString(), r("SubMenuId").ToString())
                        If dtsub.Rows.Count < 0 Then
                            sub_menu.Controls.Add(ul)
                        Else
                            For Each r1 As DataRow In dtsub.Rows
                                ul1.Controls.Add(LIList(r1("SubMenu2").ToString(), r1("SMenu2Id").ToString()))
                            Next
                            sub_menu2.Controls.Add(ul1)
                            mains.Controls.Add(sub_menu2)
                        End If
                    Else

                    End If
                Next
                sub_menu.Controls.Add(mains)
                'sub_menu.Controls.Add(ul)
                main.Controls.Add(sub_menu)

            Else
                If row("Menus") = "Home" Or row("Menus") = "About" Then
                    main.Controls.Add(LIList(row("Menus").ToString(), row("Menuid").ToString()))
                Else

                End If

            End If
        Next
        Panel1.Controls.Add(main)
    End Sub
    Private Function UList(ByVal id As String, ByVal cssClass As String) As HtmlGenericControl
        Dim ul As New HtmlGenericControl("ul")
        ul.ID = id
        ul.Attributes.Add("class", cssClass)
        Return ul
    End Function
    Private Function LIList(ByVal innerHtml As String, ByVal rel As String) As HtmlGenericControl
        Dim li As New HtmlGenericControl("li")
        li.Attributes.Add("rel", rel)
        li.InnerHtml = (Convert.ToString("<a href=" + ">") & innerHtml) + "</a>"
        Return li

    End Function
```

**my Aspx Coding Like**

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
   <title>jQuery Simple Dropdown Menu or Menu with Submenu</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../jqwidgets/styles/jqx.summer.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../scripts/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxcore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxmenu.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$('.menu ul li').hover(
function () {
$('.sub_menu', this).stop(true, true).slideDown(); /*slideDown the subitems on mouseover*/
}, function () {
$('.sub_menu', this).stop(true, true).slideUp();  /*slideUp the subitems on mouseout*/
});
});

</script>
  <style type="text/css">
   .menu ul ul {
    display: none;
}

    .menu ul li:hover > ul {
        display: block;
    }
    .menu ul {
    background: #efefef; 
    background: linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%);  
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%); 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%,#bbbbbb 100%); 
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    padding: 0 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;  
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-table;
}
    .menu ul:after {
        content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
    }

    .menu ul li {
    float: left;
}
    .menu ul li:hover {
        background: #4b545f;
        background: linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%,#5f6975 40%);
    }
        .menu ul li:hover a {
            color: #fff;
        }

    .menu ul li a {
        display: block; padding: 25px 40px;
        color: #757575; text-decoration: none;
    }

    .menu ul ul {
    background: #5f6975; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0;
    position: absolute; top: 100%;
}
    .menu ul ul li {
        float: none; 
        border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
        position: relative;
    }
        .menu ul ul li a {
            padding: 15px 40px;
            color: #fff;
        }   
            .menu ul ul li a:hover {
                background: #4b545f;
            }

            .menu ul ul ul {
    position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0;
}

  </style>
</head>
<body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
         <div align="left" >
        <asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat ="server" ></asp:Label>
        </div>
        <div align="right" >
        <asp:Button ID="login1" Text ="Log Out" runat ="server" />
        </div>
    <div class="menu">
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
        </asp:Panel>
    </div>
    </form>
    <p>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is a menu control in asp.net. http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Using-ASPNet-Menu-control-with-example-in-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Comment: I want to display that arrow symbol in dynamically,, because i Did that Menu Controls Dynamically using css and Vb , Datas From Database,, SO that Arrow symbol also i want to display dynamically,, how to do that?

Comment: Can you share _that_ code

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kb3gN/5630/

Comment: check that Jsfiddele,, just add that code,,

Comment: post code out here please. If possible make it such that we can reproduce it.

Comment: You can also use this menu: http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxmenu/defaultfunctionality.htm?arctic